# Speedy Google indexing

Tags: discussion

I asked this question an hour ago:

[Odd entries in DNS lookup log](https://serverfault.com/questions/352914/odd-entries-in-dns-lookup-log)

The question contained the string "xdnrhkbqnn".  If I now Google this string I get just one hit, namely my question.

How did Google get to index this page so quickly. Is there a way in which Serverfault.com gets pages indexed quickly?

Comment: This is technically off topic, but i'd love to know the answer.

Comment: P.S. this site isn't a 'forum', it's a Q&A site, which makes a huge difference to how much other people love it, which directly increases its google popularity and ranking, and thus indexing speed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are our questions indexed/googlable so fast?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6152/how-are-our-questions-indexed-googlable-so-fast)

Answer (score 11):

You have to be really, really, really popular and have a really, really, really fast site. See [How do Stack Overflow questions appear in Google search results in seconds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67246/how-do-stack-overflow-questions-appear-in-google-search-results-in-seconds)

There's also this one:

[How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines)

the short answer is, that Google decided to do this themselves - it wasn't something that anyone from stack exchange did.

Comment: "Google lives here" :-)

Comment: +1 You don't come to Google and talk to a man like Moe Greene like that! Google comes to you.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff answered a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/eeeeek-where-is-my-slow-performance/84701#84701) over at M.SO in relation to why the SE network of sites are *so fast*.

The answer you are looking for (note that this doesn't mention SF, just "us", so I'm presuming all the sites.):

> Google's crawler is now indexing us at, and I am not making this up,
>   **10 requests per second**, which is the maximum.

Lots of quick, topical, regularly updating content is working in SE's favour.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's just pure luck in that googlebot may have been checking the site at about the same time you were posting. I've had the same happen to my own (very low traffic) site.

Comment: Google really does index the SE network crazy fast (at least the main 3 sites). Every time I post something, it shows up in Google about 30 seconds later. its so fast infact, that we often get people who are mildly mentally handicapped posting things like "omg did you try google? You can find the answer on their duuhbrain", and then when you check the google query they post, the only thing you see is this very question. True story, happened to me the other day.

Comment: @Mark, perhaps they keep bots parked on really busy sites.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Saw this too :)